# Can a person who died count to a minyan?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, malach-angel, eliyahu-hanavi, tefillah-betzibbur

There are many stories, such as an account that one year when there was a person missing for the minyan in Chevron for the Yamim Neoraim Avraham Avinu showed up to be the tenth, (an angel? with Rav Chaim Volozhin) of people and/or being who are no longer alive, answering brachos and being the tenth to a minyan. Would does this actually work halachically?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya  Uriel ! Interesting question

Comment: Could the son of the Shunamit not count for a Minyan for the rest of his life?

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought he asked if a niftar could count while they are niftar.

Comment: @David was Avraham dead when he was answering Amen?

Comment: @DoubleAA Technically yes, but the Medrash held him as being alive as far as his soul and power to pray (that's my undersatnding)? Do you mean to say Abraham was ressurected in this world whenever he prayed? Then he was buried again? In any case the son of Shunamit was back to life like any normal person?

Comment: @David what does it mean to be technically dead but standing there answering Amen? Sounds like a word game. (Being called alive while in the grave is an allowable Chiddush. Being called alive when you aren't in the grave but actually up and living is trivial.)

Comment: https://jewish-education.tumblr.com/post/162953188319/keshetchai-ameliarating-3tznius5this

Comment: My father, A"H, wrote a story about a similar topic. I hope this link works https://rosends.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=lSdVZWUBAAA.jVgRi7r-JLAq-4eKbFrnx017HAVrByXAMJJTB2HALcAlxdNJAfjrB7lP-H8lirZv_kx6F7l5VLPfQ7fEj_mApw.NV-XTN1VSzDQgznR2i1Pfw&postId=7711802961117432017&type=POST

Comment: @rosends Link doesn't work for me - "invalid security token" whatever that means.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok can you try this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckf7o40e8kq4vpg/dead%20but%20present.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 10):

The Sefer Chassdim siman 1129 writes that Rebbi after he passed away wpuld come dressed in his shabbas clothes and recite kiddush rabbah for his family and be motzei them. The question that is asked how can he be motzei his family if the passuk in tehillim states bmeisim chafshi. The answer that is given is from the gemara in brachos 18a that Tzadikim are called alive even while they are deceased. So in theory a tzadik that comes back seems like they cam be motzei others simce they are called alive. There is also a story about Rav Yose Haglili( Sefer Yechusei 
Tannaim and Amoraim (chelek 2: Reb Yossi Haglili)  making havdalah for his family as well.

Text of Sefer Chassidim:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a source for using the gemara in brachos to explain the Sefer Chassidim?

Comment: The Sefer Chassidim uses the same language ,he is using that gemara

Comment: I'd be very wary of using aggadatah for halocha. However there was a minority opinion in Tosfos - R'Chaim Hacohen IIRC, who said he would have gone to R'Tam's funeral using the same logic. We do not rule like him